# Play Audio File during an outgoing/incoming call in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiorecorder

I am thinking of developing an application which will act like an IVR so when the user calls a number and does not want to talk instead he/she wants the called up number to listen to a pre-recorded sound. A sound will be played and called number will hear that.

I have tried searching for any thread which could have discussion about this however did not find anything. I know how to record a sound but I don't know the procedure to play the same in a phone call.

One work-around I can get that to put the speaker phone on and play the audio using MusicPlayer however that does not full-fill my requirement.

I don't want speaker to be used.

I followed these URL, and some of them said it's not possible. Is it true?

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293065/play-an-audio-file-during-the-call)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119041/issue-with-playing-music-file-during-a-phone-calling-ios-sdk)

Comment: if you found link that not-possible task then why you are asking this question. and there is answer accepted it means that is impossible task. you can not do that. you can't interaction apple native functionality by your application.

Comment: Okay @NitinGohel..what if I want to use it inside my organization and not release it in app store? is it possible to make this kind of app using any kind of library?

Comment: NOT at all apple not allow.ios app is Sandboxed so you can't access any directories outside your App directory. There are no Cocoa Touch or Objective C API's to access