# Is it possible wire in pre recorded audio in an iPhone phone call?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, core-telephony

I want to play a pre-recorded audio file in an ongoing call on the iPhone. I don't mind using third party APIs as I'm going to be using the app only for myself. Are there any CoreTelephony APIs for doing this? Please help.

Comment: You can't control iPhone ringer via API. Only user can change the melody through Settings menu

Comment: @NSDmitry I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. I want to play an audio file through the call which the person on the other end will hear.

Comment: Hm... It's not possible to access call itself. So I guess only thing you can do is to play louder sound in your app and hope iPhone noise cancelling won't mute it for your phone mate.

Comment: Duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823196/play-audio-file-during-an-outgoing-incoming-call-in-ios